# Как убрать Action Bar в Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: android, xamarin

Может вопрос задан неверно, но всё же озвучу. При замене в App.xaml.cs

```
        MainPage = new MainPage();
```

на

```
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

вверху окна появилась синяя широкая полоса. Как её убрать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Если убрать toolbar. То нужно добавить в MainPage.xaml.cs:

   ```
     NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
   ```
2. Если убрать status bar. На самом деле сущ. еще варианты. Однако мой вариант позволяет из каждой Page управлять видимостью status bar'a. Если это необходимо.

2.1 То нужно добавить в MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
DependencyService.Get<IStatusBar>().HideStatusBar();
```

2.2 Создать интерфейс IStatusBar в проекте где лежит MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public interface IStatusBar
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Hide
    /// </summary>
    void HideStatusBar();

    /// <summary>
    /// Show
    /// </summary>
    void ShowStatusBar();
}
```

2.3 И в проекте Андройд:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(StatusBarHelper))]

public class StatusBarHelper : IStatusBar
{
    private WindowManagerFlags _originalFlags;
    private bool IsHide { get; set; }

    #region IStatusBar implementation

    /// <summary>
    /// Hide
    /// </summary>
    public void HideStatusBar()
    {
        if (IsHide) return;

        IsHide = true;

        var activity = (AppCompatActivity)Forms.Context;
        var attrs = activity.Window.Attributes;
        _originalFlags = attrs.Flags;
        attrs.Flags |= WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen;
        activity.Window.Attributes = attrs;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Show
    /// </summary>
    public void ShowStatusBar()
    {
        if (!IsHide) return;

        IsHide = false;

        var activity = (AppCompatActivity)Forms.Context;
        var attrs = activity.Window.Attributes;
        attrs.Flags = _originalFlags;
        activity.Window.Attributes = attrs;
    }

    #endregion
}
```